# About the $Z_2$ topological invariant

Tags: topology, topological-order, topological-insulators, majorana-fermions, topological-phase

In [Kitaev 2001](http://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1070/1063-7869/44/10S/S29/meta) it is shown that the topological invariant $Z_2$ in a topological superconductor (Class D or BDI, one dimensional) can be defined as 
$$
(-1)^\nu={\rm sign\, Pf} [ A ]={\rm sign\, Pf}[ \tilde{A}(k=0)]\cdot {\rm sign\, Pf}[ \tilde{A}(k=\pi)]
$$
where $A$ is the Hamiltonian of the system in the Majorana representation, and $\tilde{A}(k)$ is its Fourier transform, and $\rm Pf$ is the Pfaffian.
Therefore one needs to calculate the Pfaffian only at the high-symmetry points $k=0$ and $k=\pi$.

How general is this identity? 
It is possible to generalize the identity to other classes of superconductors (e.g., classes C) and other dimensions (e.g., $d=2$ in class D and DIII)?

Note on class D: in this class the topological invariant is $Z$ for $d=2$ but the Pfaffian invariant $(-1)^\nu={\rm sign\, Pf} [ A ]$ still describes the "parity" of the invariant $Z$.

**EDIT:** Does one needs some special symmetries, such as, centrosymmetry or inversion parity, or this identity is really general?
Regarding the dimensionality, does this identity generalize in higher dimensions simply to:
$$
(-1)^\nu={\rm sign\, Pf} [ A ]=\prod_{\bf k=-k}{\rm sign\, Pf}[ \tilde{A}(k)]
$$
where the product is taken over all $\bf k$ in the $d$-dimensional Brillouin zone such that $\bf k=-k$?